# Failed to create multiple redis connections in Laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5.8

I am trying to create multiple Redis connection in Laravel Command. It just let me create one connection in it and for others, it fails with error

```
InvalidArgumentException  : Redis connection [redis_db] not configured.

at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php:116
```

My `database.php` looks like

```
    'redis' => ['client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
        'prefix'  => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_',
    ],

    'psh' => [
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 5),
    ],

    'redis_db' => [
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 3),
    ],
],
```

The connection that I am creating in my command file looks like:

```
/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->redis              = Redis::connection('psh');
    $this->redisAbTest        = Redis::connection('redis_db');
}
```

I have already added Redis in my `.env` file

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Redis is `"predis/predis": "^1.1",` and laravel is `5.8.17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need multiple redis connections you need to open a new service provider for each connection and add service providers to `config/app.php`. Then you can use like

```
Redis::connection('psh');
```

```
class RedisPshProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('psh', function ($app) {
            return new RedisManager($app, 'predis', $app['config']['database.psh']);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['psh'];
    }
}
```

When you need another one, open another service provider replace `psh` with other connection name.

```
'providers' => [
    // other providers
    App\Providers\RedisPshProvider::class,
];
```